# What is the difference between these two AJAX request syntaxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there a difference between the following two [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) calls?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: someApiUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: someData
    }).success(function (payload, status, xhr) {
        //success code
    });
```

---

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: someApiUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: someData,
        success: function (payload, status, xhr) {
            //success code
        }
    });
```

If so, what are some advantages/disadvantages to each?

Bonus points if there is a better way to word this question.  Perhaps the techniques have names?

Comment: The end result is the same. Which one you use is a matter of preference. There is no technical advantage to either one.

Comment: I believe they are functionally the same.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yeah, that's why it looked odd to me

Comment: There are cases where you can only use the first pattern though - for example where a function returns the `jqXHR` object from the `$.ajax()` call. Mostly it's a preference as has already been stated, as the logic flow is otherwise identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written they are identical. With a small alteration the first can be superior to the second. To wit:

```
var $eventualResult = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: someApiUrl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: someData
});
```

Now the result is a *value*, you can pass it around, return it from a function, use it in different contexts:

```
$eventualResult.then(function (result) { /* uses the result */ });

// meanwhile, elsewhere in the codebase...

$eventualResult.then(function (result) { /* do something else */ });
```

Using the callback argument to the `$.ajax` constructor does not have this property.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Any ideas on adjusting the title of the question?  Perhaps "Success callback vs parameter"?

Comment: @RatherNotsay the callback *is* a parameter. What we are actually doing here is using Promises. Promises have their own problems, but they are superior to callbacks. Google 'Promises vs. callbacks' for further info.

Comment: so it's promise vs callback?  Thanks.

Comment: @RatherNotsay no problem. IMHO, the sooner callbacks die (at least in languages that support the alternatives) the better.

Answer (score 1):

The first instantiates the AJAX call and then appends a success event to it

The second shows a success callback method as a parameter to the AJAX call's constructor

The second is superior (in my opinion) because the intent is clearer to the developer reading it

Comment: Thanks! I also prefer the aesthetics of the second option.